# Column in scatter chart?

Tags: highcharts

this is the code:

```
 $(function () {

// Give the points a 3D feel by adding a radial gradient
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.4,
            cy: 0.3,
            r: 0.5
        },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.2).get('rgb')]
        ]
    };
});

// Set up the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        margin: 100,
        type: 'scatter',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 30,
            depth: 250,
            viewDistance: 5,

            frame: {
                bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)' },
                back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)' },
                side: { size: 8, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)' }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Draggable box'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click and drag the plot area to rotate in space'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            depth: 10
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    zAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Reading',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [[8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 7], [6, 9, 6], [7, 0, 5], [2, 3, 3], [3, 9, 8], [3, 6, 5], [4, 9, 4], [2, 3, 3], [6, 9, 9], [0, 7, 0], [7, 7, 9], [7, 2, 9], [0, 6, 2], [4, 6, 7], [3, 7, 7], [0, 1, 7], [2, 8, 6], [2, 3, 7], [6, 4, 8], [3, 5, 9], [7, 9, 5], [3, 1, 7], [4, 4, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 1, 6], [6, 8, 5], [6, 6, 7], [4, 1, 1], [7, 2, 7], [7, 7, 0], [8, 8, 9], [9, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4], [9, 8, 9], [3, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4], [6, 0, 2], [2, 1, 3], [5, 8, 9], [2, 1, 1], [9, 7, 6], [3, 0, 2], [9, 9, 0], [3, 4, 8], [2, 6, 1], [8, 9, 2], [7, 6, 5], [6, 3, 1], [9, 3, 1], [8, 9, 3], [9, 1, 0], [3, 8, 7], [8, 0, 0], [4, 9, 7], [8, 6, 2], [4, 3, 0], [2, 3, 5], [9, 1, 4], [1, 1, 4], [6, 0, 2], [6, 1, 6], [3, 8, 8], [8, 8, 7], [5, 5, 0], [3, 9, 6], [5, 4, 3], [6, 8, 3], [0, 1, 5], [6, 7, 3], [8, 3, 2], [3, 8, 3], [2, 1, 6], [4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 9], [5, 4, 2], [6, 1, 3], [6, 9, 5], [4, 8, 2], [9, 7, 4], [5, 4, 2], [9, 6, 1], [2, 7, 3], [4, 5, 4], [6, 8, 1], [3, 4, 0], [2, 2, 6], [5, 1, 2], [9, 9, 7], [6, 9, 9], [8, 4, 3], [4, 1, 7], [6, 2, 5], [0, 4, 9], [3, 5, 9], [6, 9, 1], [1, 9, 2]]
    },
             { type: "column",
              depth: 250,
              data: [0]
             }],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 200
        }
    },
});
```

and this is jsfiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/Rodrigoson6/2yfebsgn/

I want to have a chart that reminds the very 3d. I can do only with colors and gradients. It would be very important to add another properties at the "frame" (on top), because in that way i coulde use other colors and gradients...

But is impossible.

The yAxis is reversed, because in future on bottom (that with yaxis reversed is at the top) i will add an image...
But on bottom there will be nothing....

So, i would like to add a column in my scatter chart. But i want that the only column must be at the bottom e in the chart (now the column is at the top and half outside of chart)...

Is possible ?

Maybe another solution could be to add a rect ? but the problem is that my chart is scatter type and draggable.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to do. Perhaps you can post an image of what you want it to look like ?

Comment: The frame has only 3 properties (back, side, bottom). I want to add another properties (top), but is impossible. Maybe i can add column in scatter chart? If you see jsfiddle, my yAxis is reversed, so the bottom property  is at the top of chart, and botton there is nothing. Is possible to add that column on bottom of my chart (see the code jsfiddle) ?  Now do you understand?

Comment: Unfortunately you can have only 3 axis, so rotation will not solve a problem. So it is default behavoiur and at this moment it is not possible.

Comment: Yea i understand, but another way could be to add a column at the bottom of my scatter chart? See the jsfiddle.